# How to programatically read active window title of any window opened within a Remote Desktop?

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop

I have an application which periodically reads the windows title of current active window on a persons desktop. However, when a person accesses any window using Remote Desktop then my application is only able to detect that the person is using Remote Desktop and not able to get details of the active window opened on the Remote Desktop.
Is it possible to get the above details programatically in c#?

Comment: I think you may need to use impersonation to start a process in that session which gets the information you desire. You would then have to use IPC to get it back to your process.

Comment: Does Remote Desktop have API, which provides this information? I highly doubt it.

Comment: Not possible.  The user is looking a pixels, not windows.